# libgdx actor - alpha actions not being drawn

Tags: libgdx, action, actor, alpha

I have an Image with a fadeOut/fadeIn action. Something like this:

```
public void fadeInAndOut() {
    AlphaAction actionFadeOut = new AlphaAction();
    actionFadeOut.setAlpha(0f);
    actionFadeOut.setDuration(2f);
    AlphaAction actionFadeIn = new AlphaAction();
    actionFadeIn.setAlpha(1f);
    actionFadeIn.setDuration(2f);

    this.addAction(Actions.sequence(actionFadeOut, Actions.delay(2f), actionFadeIn));
}
```

But nothing happens when calling this method.

My draw method is:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    batch.draw(objectImage, getX(), getY(), getWidth() * getScaleX(),
            getHeight() * getScaleY());
}
```

How can I make the alpha values of the image work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your actions process on act() method, you probably have overrode act method in your custom actor and not calling super.act(). Normally, stage.act process actions for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the [scene2d wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) says, we need to override **draw** like this:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    Color color = getColor();
    batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);
    batch.draw(objectImage, getX(), getY(), getWidth() * getScaleX(),
            getHeight() * getScaleY());
    batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, 1f);
}
```

And voilà...

----- UPDATE -----

I had to add after drawing next line:

```
batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, 1f);
```

otherwise in some cases the stage color was also affected and not only the actor.

Hope it helps

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be: `batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);` to properly restore things? Or just `batch.setColor(color);`?

Comment: REMARK for people who still can't make it work. I called batch.getColor() and it doesn't want to work, I didn't notice in this and other examples that you call getColor on the actor, not the batch!

Comment: If each actor sets the color they want before drawing, there is no need to call `setColor` a second time. Also, you should store the original batch color and restore that, via `batch.getColor()`, if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the alpha values of your image to work, you need to change the colour of your spriteBatch like so:

```
Color color = batch.getColor();
batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, parentAlpha); //Sets the alpha of the batch without changing the color

batch.draw(...);
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work, I don't see any alpha variation. I added this line in the draw: Gdx.app.log("xx", "alpha: " + parentAlpha); and it's always 1.0

Comment: Did you remember to enable alpha blending? `batch.enableBlending()`

Comment: color - barking not with batch but with the Actor